# Expressions versus variables in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is an issue that I've been trying to find an answer to for months but to no avail!! Why does the code snippet:-

```
Sub sbDispCellAddress_01()
ActiveCell.Address
MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

not work.
When I run it I get a Compile error:`Invalid use of property` and the 'Address ' following 'ActiveCell' is highlighted in blue.

Yet the following code snippet works fine:-

```
Sub sbDispCellAddress_02()
Dim s As String
s=ActiveCell.Address
MsgBox s
End Sub
```

so why does the top code not work?
What is it about the variable that makes the bottom code work?
Please help me get my head round this simple example.

Comment: What would you expect the top code to do? What would be the point of a line that evaluates an address but doesn't do anything with it?

Comment: Good point Rory. Thanks for your reponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA grammar is a law unto itself.

`ActiveCell.Address` is syntactically invalid *unless* it's being "used" by something, such as being assigned to a variable of an appropriate type, or as a function parameter (such as an argument to `MsgBox`).

In your case the issue goes away if you remove line immediately after `Sub sbDispCellAddress_01()`.

In this respect VBA differs from languages like C, C++, and Java, where an *expression* followed by a *statement terminator* is itself a *statement* and therefore valid.

Comment: Thank you, Bathsheba. I must remember to get my head out of C and dig deeper into VBA language.

Comment: On reflection, your above explanation sums up in a nutshell, Bathsheba, what I have been looking for for months with endless trawling the web without success. Having only taken excel VBA more seriously in the last few months, your advice has increased my understanding of the VBA language enormously. Many thanks again.